SQL Select two rows on different conditions from joined table
I have two tables, one with articles and one with their attributes.
I need to select multiple attributes for specific articles.
Articles-table:



Article
Description
Category




A00001
First item
X


A00002
Second item
X


A00003
Third item
Z



Attributes-table:



Article
Attribute
Value




A00001
Height
1000


A00001
Width
2000


A00001
Depth
3000


A00002
Height
4000


A00002
Width
5000


A00002
Depth
6000



Desired result:



Article
Description
Category
Height
Width




A00001
First item
X
1000
2000


A00002
Second item
X
4000
5000




The answers are the for the answer, not the question. If you want to self answer the question, put the answer there. I've removed the answer, to help you in the process of migrating it (you can find it in the question's revisions if you need it).

Sounds like you want something called pivot, i think there should be some previous questions/answers covering this topic quite well

DATA
CREATE TABLE Articles(
   Article     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Description VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Category    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Articles
(Article,Description,Category) VALUES 
('A00001','First item','X'),
('A00002','Second item','X'),
('A00003','Third item','Z');



CREATE TABLE Attributes(
   Article   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL  
  ,Attribute VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
  ,Value     INTEGER  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO Attributes
(Article,Attribute,Value) VALUES 
('A00001','Height',1000),
('A00001','Width',2000),
('A00001','Depth',3000),
('A00002','Height',4000),
('A00002','Width',5000),
('A00002','Depth',6000);

use Max with Case
SELECT 
  ArticleS.Article, 
  MAX(Articles.Description) Description, 
  MAX(Articles.Category) Category, 
  MAX(
    CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Height' THEN Value END
  ) Height, 
  MAX(
    CASE WHEN Attribute = 'Width' THEN Value END
  ) Width 
FROM 
  Articles 
  JOIN Attributes AS Att1 ON Articles.Article = Att1.Article 
WHERE 
  Articles.Category = 'X' 
GROUP BY 
  ArticleS.Article


dbfiddle

SELECT a.article,
       a.description,
       b.attribute,
       b.value
FROM   articletable a
       JOIN attributestable b
         ON a.article = b.article
WHERE  ( a.article = 'A00001'
          OR a.article = 'A00002' )
       AND ( b.attribute = 'Height'
              OR b.attribute = 'Width' ) 


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
